# Is Intel i5-1135G7 Iris Xe Graphics supported? Screen flickers and tears

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, flicker

I got a Lenovo Yoga 14s 2021 with ubuntu 18.04 OS installed on it this week, but the screen keeps flickering and tearing whenever the mouse moving or anything change on the screen. I've tried using kernel 5.9 and installed ubuntu 20.04, the 2.8K screen is still flickering madly.

I doubt if the Iris Xe supported by ubuntu now or there is no driver for the device.

Is there anyone can help me please. I need your help.

Comment: I just found that the screen works well on  ubuntu 20.10. I check /var/log/Xorg.0.log and notice ubuntu 20.10 uses X.Org X Server 1.20.9 while ubuntu 20.04/18.04 uses X.Org X Server 1.20.8. I think it is the video driver matters.
So, now the problem is how to upgrade X.Org X Server ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after struggling for several days, I found 20.10 worked well.

BTW, to enable the keyboard, modified `/etc/default/grub` at line 10 as follows:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd i8042.reset=0"` . Check [kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) here.

And then everything runs well. Except that I need to compile ROS noetic from source which took me another two days.

Comment: Did you have to change any settings besides the grub line?